# sparql delete query optimization

Tags: insert, sparql

I have a query delete/insert that I'd like to optimize if possible. The query does delete/insert on up to 50 objects at a time. My Jmeter tests show that the DELETE clause takes 4 times longer in  comparison to INSERT: delete takes around 3300 ms and insert takes about 860 ms. I'd like to improve the DELETE clause. I was thinking of using FILTER, but was told it would not scale well. Any recommendation is much appreciated.
What I have right now is:

```
DELETE { 
?s ?p ?o.
?collection dc:identifier  ?cid;
    rdf:type  ?ct;
    rdf:li  ?list.
?list   rdf:first ?first; 
    rdf:rest  ?rest.
} 
WHERE
{
    { ?s dc:identifier "11111"^^xsd:int; ?p ?o. } 
    UNION { ?s dc:identifier "22222"^^xsd:int; ?p ?o.} 
    UNION {?s dc:identifier "33333"^^xsd:int; ?p ?o.} 
    UNION{} UNION{}.......

    OPTIONAL{
        ?s  dc:hasPart ?collection.
        ?collection dc:identifier  ?cid;
            rdf:type    ?ct;
            rdf:li  ?list.
        ?list   rdf:first ?first;
           rdf:rest  ?rest.
}
INSERT DATA 
{
    GRAPH <http://test.org/>
    {.....}
    GRAPH <http://test.org/>
    {.....}
    GRAPH....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having your data, or even knowing what triple store you're using, we can't really help much in optimization.  It might just be that deletes are more expensive than insertions.  That said, one thing that *might* help is to use **values** rather than **union**s in your **where** block.  That is, instead of:

```
{ ?s dc:identifier "11111"^^xsd:int; ?p ?o. } 
UNION { ?s dc:identifier "22222"^^xsd:int; ?p ?o.} 
UNION {?s dc:identifier "33333"^^xsd:int; ?p ?o.} 
UNION{} UNION{}.......
```

do:

```
values ?identifier { "11111"^^xsd:int "22222"^^xsd:int "33333"^^xsd:int "44444"^^xsd:int }
?s dc:identifier ?identifier ; ?p ? o
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion - I tried using values, but the speed for delete remains unchanged. It was worth a shot though.

Comment: @user2917629 Do you have any reason to suppose that the delete is running slower than it "ought to"? Your "delete where" requires a query, and then constructing triples based on the query.  The "insert data" just inserts literal data.  To me, it makes sense that the "delete where" would take longer.

Comment: Yes, you are right, delete has a lot more to do. I was able to cut back 200 ms by adding more OPTIONS in teh WHERE clause, so I guess I'll leave it at that.